# Angular how to send get request to node

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angular

I have a node server running at port 8000

```
app.get('/historical/:days' ,(req,res,next){..})
```

How do I make a a request from angular(port 4200) from the browser to the node server?
I do the following

```
makeRequest(): void {
this.loading = true;
this.http.get('http://localhost:8000/historical/:day')
.subscribe(data => {

  this.data = data;
  console.log(this.data)
  this.loading = false; });
```

}

at the html side of angular:

```
<pre>
<div>
  {{makeRequest()}}
</div>

</pre>
```

When I type `http://localhost:4200/historical/1`, (where 1 represents historical data of the previous day)
nothing happens

What to do?

Comment: Is your angular router navigating to the correct path after you change the address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one I would not call the `makeRequest` function from your html. Angular is going to fire this method every time the change detection cycle runs (alot of api requests). Instead I would include it in your ngOnInit lifecycle hook

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.makeRequest();
}
```

Since your node server is running on localhost:8000, then

```
this.http.get('http://localhost:8000/historical/1').subscribe(...);
```

should work. If you want to hit localhost:4200 for an api request, you are going to need to proxy your api calls from localhost:4200 to localhost:8000. [Angular CLI proxy docs](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md)

Comment: It solved some of the problems. But now when I type
`http://localhost:4200/historical/4` or `http://localhost:4200/historical/2`
It does not show the data for day 4 or day 2 resp.  but instrad shows me the latest data.
Whereas if I type the same for node server `http://localhost:8000/historical/4`, it shows the correct data

Comment: @Steve what do you mean by latest data?

Comment: On hindsight, a question came into my mind.

Why do I even need node to serve data from a DB to angular? Why can't I directly request (query) data from DB in angular (skipping the request to node, which then the node server makes request to DB and then give data to angular.

Comment: @Steve There are a couple of issues with that. 1: directly querying the db from angular requires you to expose your database credentials on the client which is a huge security risk. (There are some exceptions like firebase where this is the case, but the db is locked down by rules). 2: The chain has to be angular -> node -> db -> node -> angular. You can't do angular -> db -> node -> angular because if angular makes the request to the db, the db wants to respond to angular. It does not and won't know to respond to node because node did not make the request.

Comment: Thank you for elucidating and helping me to understand the general web app architecture. You are awesome!

Are there any other reasons( apart from security) for which the rigor is to make calls `angular -> node -> db -> node -> angular`, instead (removing node in the picture)  `angular -> db -> angular`

Comment: @Steve I would say security is the biggest issue. Another thing to consider is data processing. Say your webpage needs some data that is composed of 3+ tables in your database. You can have your server(node) handle this processing/compiling of data in a single api. So ultimately your client(angular) only has to hit 1 endpoint as opposed to 3+.